# Java Blackjack card total counting

Tags: java, counting, blackjack

Here is the entirety of my Hand class below:

The question that I have is that when I run the program, it gives me output like:

> "Welcome to blackjack...dealing 2 cards:
>
> Here are your cards: [AH, 3S]
> 10 , (h)it or (s)tand?
> "

An Ace of Hearts and a 3 of spades should not give me 10. I do not know what's wrong with my code. My `getSoftTotal()` method looks like it should work fine (I haven't bothered with my `getHardTotal()` method yet.

Here's another output:

> "Here are your cards: [4D, 10D]
> 25 , (h)it or (s)tand? "

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hand extends Deck {

    private static ArrayList<Card> cards;

    public Hand() {

        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    public void addCard(Card other) {

        cards.add(other);
    }

    public static boolean hasBlackjack() {

        boolean ace = true;
        boolean ten = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
            if (!(cards.get(i).getValue() == Card.ACE))
                ace = false;
            if (!(cards.get(i).getValue() == 10))
                ten = false;
        }
        return (ace && ten);
    }

    public static boolean isBusted() {
        return getTotal() > 21;

    }

    public static int getSoftTotal() {
        int total = 0;
        for (Card card : cards) {
            total += card.getValue();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static int getTotal() {

        return getSoftTotal(); // soft
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Deck deck; // A deck of cards. A new deck for each game.
        String hit = "";

        Hand hand = new Hand();
        deck = new Deck();
        deck.shuffle();

        System.out.println("Welcome to blackjack...dealing 2 cards:");
        System.out.println("");

        hand.addCard(deck.deal());
        hand.addCard(deck.deal());

        do {
            System.out.println("Here are your cards: " + cards.toString());
            hand.addCard(deck.deal());
            System.out.println(hand.getTotal() + " , (h)it or (s)tand? ");
            System.out.println("");
            hit = input.nextLine();
        } while (hit.equals("h") && isBusted() == false
                && hasBlackjack() == false);

        if (isBusted() == true) {
            System.out.println("BUSTED!  YOU LOSE!");
        }
        if (hasBlackjack() == true) {
            System.out.println("BLACKJACK!  YOU WIN!");
        }
        if (hit.equals("s") && isBusted() == false) {
            System.out.println("You ended with " + getTotal());
        }
    }

}
```

**Card.java**

```
public class Card {

public final static int CLUBS = 0;
public final static int HEARTS = 1;
public final static int SPADES = 2;
public final static int DIAMONDS = 3;

// Numbers for the values
public final static int ACE = 1;
public final static int JACK = 11;
public final static int QUEEN = 12;
public final static int KING = 13;

/**
 * This card's suit, one of the constants SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS,
 * or JOKER. The suit cannot be changed after the card is constructed.
 */
private final int suit;

/**
 * The card's value. For a normal cards, this is one of the values 1 through
 * 13, with 1 representing ACE. For a JOKER, the value can be anything. The
 * value cannot be changed after the card is constructed.
 */
private final int value;

/**
 * Creates a card with a specified suit and value.
 * 
 * @param theValue
 *            the value of the new card. For a regular card (non-joker), the
 *            value must be in the range 1 through 13, with 1 representing
 *            an Ace. You can use the constants Card.ACE, Card.JACK,
 *            Card.QUEEN, and Card.KING. For a Joker, the value can be
 *            anything.
 * @param theSuit
 *            the suit of the new card. This must be one of the values
 *            Card.SPADES, Card.HEARTS, Card.DIAMONDS, Card.CLUBS, or
 *            Card.JOKER.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if the parameter values are not in the Permissible ranges
 */
public Card(int cardValue, int cardSuit) {
    if (cardSuit > 3 || cardSuit < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal card suit:" + cardSuit);
    if (cardValue > 13 || cardValue < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal card value:"
                + cardValue);
    value = cardValue;
    suit = cardSuit;
}

public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public String getSuitString() {
    switch (suit) {

    case CLUBS:
        return "C";
    case HEARTS:
        return "H";
    case SPADES:
        return "S";
    case DIAMONDS:
        return "D";
    default:
        return "";
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a String representation of the card's value.
 * 
 * @return for a regular card, one of the strings "Ace", "2", "3", ...,
 *         "10", "Jack", "Queen", or "King". For a Joker, the string is
 *         always numerical.
 */
public String getValueString() {

    switch (value) {
    case 1:
        return "A";
    case 2:
        return "2";
    case 3:
        return "3";
    case 4:
        return "4";
    case 5:
        return "5";
    case 6:
        return "6";
    case 7:
        return "7";
    case 8:
        return "8";
    case 9:
        return "9";
    case 10:
        return "10";
    case 11:
        return "J";
    case 12:
        return "Q";
    case 13:
        return "K"; // Default will return King if it's not any of those up

    default:
        return "";

    }
}

public String toString() {

    return getValueString() + "" + getSuitString();
}

public boolean equals(Card other) {

    if (this.value == other.value && this.suit == other.suit){
        return true;}
    else{
    
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Card a = new Card(10, 3);
    System.out.println(a.toString());

    // Card b = new Card(14, 3); //ThrowsIllegalArgumentException
    // System.out.println(b.toString());

    Card c = new Card(1, 2);
    System.out.println(c.toString());
    
    Card equals1Yes = new Card(2, 3);
    Card equals2Yes = new Card(2, 3);
    
    Card notEquals = new Card(3, 2);
    
    System.out.println(equals1Yes.equals(equals2Yes));
    System.out.println(notEquals.equals(equals1Yes));
    
    System.out.println(a.getSuit());
    System.out.println(a.getValue());
    
    System.out.println(a.getValueString());
    System.out.println(a.getSuitString());
    

    
    

}

} // end class Card
```

**Deck.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deck {

private ArrayList<Card> cards;

public Deck() {
    cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    for (int a = 1; a <= 13; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b <= 3; b++) {
            cards.add(new Card(a, b));
        }
    }

}

public Card deal() {
    if (cards.size() != 0) {
        return cards.remove(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

public String toString() {
    String return1 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= cards.size(); i++) {
        return1 = +cards.indexOf(i) + " ";
    }
    return return1;

}

public int size() {
    return cards.size();
}

public void shuffle() {

    Collections.shuffle(cards);
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (cards.size() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

public void reset() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    

}
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see your `Card` class.

Comment: I have added the Card class.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like we need to see the `Deck` class too, since that's apparently where you're assigning values to cards.

Comment: I have added the Deck class. (I appreciate the help).

Comment: Please don't delete your code after people on here help you.  It might be helpful for other people to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in your `Hand` main method.  After you display the initial two cards in the hand, you're dealing an extra card.

```
System.out.println("Here are your cards: " + cards.toString());
hand.addCard(deck.deal());
```

This extra card's value is being included in the total value of the hand in the next line.  I think your code will (mostly) work if you remove the second line above.

---

Additional note: I think some of your hands will be calculated wrong according to the rules of Blackjack because you have the values of the face cards set up incorrectly in your card model.  Jack, Queen, and King should all have a value of 10.

Comment: Thank you for the response! (Sorry you had to read all that code for a simple error like that.)  

Also, for my program we are using different values for those cards (but thanks for the warning).

Answer (score 0):

You've got more problems than the one pointed out by Bill. Your `hasBlackjack()` and `getTotal()` functions are both wrong, and you don't make any distinction between hard and soft totals, which will be necessary to move on. There's probably more after that, but one bug at a time... Also, NEVER suppress warnings. They're there for a reason. If you're getting a warning, FIX THE CODE, don't suppress it.

Here's a working `hasBlackjack()`. I'll leave the `getTotal()` fixes to you, but your first hint is that card values 10, 11, 12, and 13 should all add 10 to the total. With your class, `value > 9` can be used to check for a 10-count card.

```
public static boolean hasBlackjack() {
    if (cards.size() != 2) return false;
    return ((cards.get(0).getValue() == Card.ACE && cards.get(1).getValue() > 9) ||
        (cards.get(1).getValue() == Card.ACE && cards.get(0).getValue() > 9));
}
```